In DAX generate a measure that creates daily snapshot data from non-snapshot data
I would love if someone could help me with something I am struggling with in DAX.
I have a fact table something like the following:



Date
Product
Customer
Value




2024/1/15
Prod 1
Cust A
1


2024/3/21
Prod 1
Cust A
2


2024/5/11
Prod 1
Cust A
3


2024/9/29
Prod 1
Cust A
2


2024/11/11
Prod 1
Cust A
1



And similar data for Prod 2 and Cust B etc
I want to create a DAX measure that will give me the most recent value for every date in the calendar year, including dates not in the fact table. Something that will also allow aggregation of the most recent values from all the Products and Customers on that date.
I can get something working when using only Date and Value in the fact table but it gets too complicated when I add in Product and Customer.
I would be very grateful for any help.
I tried the following that works for date and value only but not for aggregating different products and customers
LatestValue =
var _latestDate = max(tblCalendar[Date])
 var _latestDataDate = CALCULATE(max(tblData[Date]),  tblCalendar[Date] <= _latestDate)
 var _latestData = CALCULATE(sum(tblData[Value]), tblCalendar[Date] = _latestDataDate)
 RETURN _latestData


Can you please provide an example of the output you are expecting?

"The most recent value for every day on the calendar" doesn't make sense to me. Do you want a value for every day on the calendar or the most recent date?

Sorry, I should have been more clear. I have a dataset of data that is non-agregatable across dates and the values are updated only a few times per year.  On any day of the year I want to present the latest value that has been recorded.

I assume that you are asking to display the sales from the most recent day with sales, even on days where no sales are recorded.  It would help if you could show the expected output in your question.  Anyway, here is one way you can achieve this result:
    Latest Sales = 
    VAR CurrentDate = MAX('Date'[Date])
    VAR LatestSalesDate =
        CALCULATE(
            MAX(Sales[Date]),
            Sales[Date] <= CurrentDate, 
            REMOVEFILTERS(Sales[Date])
        )
    RETURN
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(Sales[Value]),
            Sales[Date] = LatestSalesDate
        )


This is a HUGE help, thank you. That works perfect if there is only 1 product and 1 customer. I've taken your code and used it inside SUMX. The below now seems to work, there are probably more efficient ways of doing it.

LatestValueAcrossCustProd =
VAR MaxDate = MAX('Date'[Date])
VAR CustProdList =
CALCULATETABLE(
SUMMARIZE(tblData,tblData[Product],tblData[Customer),
'Date'[Date] <= MaxDate
)
RETURN
SUMX(CustProdList,[Latest Sales])

@BGSteve - the code was just a template for you to adapt for your purposes. Glad you found it useful. If this answer for useful for you, please accept it and/or upvote it. Cheers.
